# Rails 5 is serving old assets on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, tinymce, asset-pipeline

My `Rails` 5 application is behaving weirdly. The application is on `heroku`.

I am using the gem `tinymce-rails`. Recently, this gem got updated to version 5 which uses new functions. After deployment I faced an issue where one of the plugins (the `link` plugin) could not be loaded due to using the old syntax.

I am using `chrome` to open the website. For some reason the `tinymce` plugins javascript files are not up to date. They also don't have that fingerprinted name with the hash in the end. All other javascript files do however.

I ran `heroku run rake assets:precompile; heroku run rake assets:clobber;`. It was no good.

I then tried to open the website in `incognito` mode and found that the `tinymce` plugins are the up to date ones. Still though without the fingerprinted file names.

1. How can I force that the old plugin javascript files be invalidated? I will not have control over my users to ask them to clear their caches.
2. How can I force using the fingerprinted files? I have inspected the `heroku` server file system and found `assets/tinymce/plugins/link`
   having both fingerprinted and non-fingerprinted files however the non fingerprinted files were the ones used.

Comment: How are you referencing those assets on the code?

Comment: I am referencing them normally using `<%= javascript_include_tag "tinymce" %>` `<%= javascript_include_tag "admins/tinymce" %>` inside the `.erb` file. The first one is to include the `gem` files and the second one is to include the file where I call `tinymce.init`.

Comment: Did you add those file names to the assets precompile config array? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: I have `admins/tinymce` added to `assets.rb` precompile line. I don't think I should add the javascript files that are inside the `tinymce` `gem`.